# How to send integers to arduino via serial?

Tags: c, unicode, serial-port, arduino

I want to send integers to Arduino via a serial connection.
For example, when I send "1" the data received by Arduino is "49"
and when I send "a" the data received by Arduino is "97"

There are two functions in [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29), `ord()` and `unichr()`.  They behaved like this:

```
unichr(97) = u"a"
ord(u"a")=97
```

Are there equivalent C functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [the alphanumeric to integer function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atoi).

You may also find *[header cstdlib, stdlib.h, C Standard General Utilities Library](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/)* useful. Although it says C++, this particular section is the standard C library. Notice that you can use C++ with Arduino.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you have your characters stored as their ASCII-value, the easiest way - if your goal is converting *single* digits - is to subtract the ASCII-value of 0: `'8'-'0'` will give you the unsigned char value 8. You need to make sure it's a digit and not some character, but that is easily done by just checking if the result is below or equal 9.

Similarly, you get the ASCII-value of a single digit z by adding the value of '0'.